# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with ALB: Node Websocket times out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've read several blog posts and followed their instructions on how to get Node Websockets to work with AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB) using Application Load Balancer (ALB) - to no avail.

App works properly with Websockets when used locally (`localhost`).

In EB, App loads properly and displays in Browser, but the Websocket does not connect and eventually times out.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://tradey-12-hr-dev.ap-northeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:3030/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

As per the blog posts, I've made the following addition to my app in `.ebextensions/enable-websockets.config`:

```
container_commands:
  enable_websockets:
    command: |
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
              ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

Here is the back end code that sets up the websocket. Port used is `3030` in both BE and FE.

```
import WebSocket from 'ws'

const setUpWebsocketServer = port => new WebSocket.Server({ port })

export default setUpWebsocketServer
```

Here is the front end code that initiates the handshake:

```
const target = window.location.host === 'localhost:3000' ? 
  'localhost' : window.location.host

const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${target}:${PORT}`)
```

Here is a link to the last 100 lines of logs. No errors are being generated:

https://gist.github.com/bengrunfeld/e2f46e3575a3f57a68ed3c39fd63e7d8

I'm hoping that this is something small, and my gut tells me that I have to allow traffic to port `3030` via Security Groups or something - I even created new Inbound Traffic rules on all security groups allowing traffic from 'Anywhere', but this also did not work (see attached image).

Thanks for your help in advance =)

[image: AWS EC2 Security Group Inbound Rules]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. ALB only supports HTTP, not TCP. True Websockets (e.g. npm ws library) run over TCP, so they won't work with ALB. Either you can use true Websockets with ELB or a library that falls back to Long Polling like Socket.io with ALB. I've written a full blog post about it which you can read here: https://medium.com/@binyamin/node-websockets-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-elastic-load-balancer-elb-or-application-load-6a693b21415a